# What is the worst-case time-complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, big-o

```
void intFunction (int n, int value)
{
     int b,c;
     for (int j = 4; j < n; j++) {
          for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
               b *= val;
               for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
                    c += b;
          }
     }
}
```

I just learned the Big-O notion. so for this code, from my understand, the outside loop run time is n, and second inner one runs n(n+1)/2, and inner one is n(n+1)/2 as well. so the running time would be O(N^5)? am I right?

Comment: No you are wrong. Outer loop is O(n), inner one is O(n), and the inner most one is O(n). In total you have O(n^3).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asymptotic analysis.

Comment: @Juan, `j` starts at 4 but goes up to `n - 1`.

Comment: @tmyklebu: [Not off topic for SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228577/on-which-stack-exchange-should-questions-about-asymptotic-runtime-complexity-ana)

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: Sure it is.  It has nothing to do with programming; the CS stackexchange is the right place for this question if anything is.  (Aside from that, this question is almost certainly a duplicate many times over.)

Answer (score 2):

Solving the following formula would give you the exact number of iterations (and deduce the order of growth complexity):

[image]

Result **empirically** verified!

Comment: i see. what about the middle loop? its not summation?

Comment: I am seeing three loops, as I am seering three summations. I am not sure what your question is about.

Answer (score 2):

The outer loop:

```
for (int j = 4; j < n; j++)
```

iterates `n - 4` times, so it is O(n). The inner loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
```

iterates at most `n - 5` times, so this is also `O(n)`. The inner most one:

```
for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
```

iterates `n` times so it is O(n). The final complexity is `O(n * n * n) = O(n^3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go with the number of iterations TO get verified about time-complexity!

First loop--->

```
for (int j = 4; j < n; j++){...}  // it will iterate for n-4 times.
```

Second loop--->

```
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++){...}  //it'll iterate for j-1 times for each iteration of outer loop started by j. See,this is dependent on First Loop(the outermost loop)...
```

Third Loop--->

```
for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k){...}  //it'll always run n times independent to any previous-iteration whenever it is executed
```

So, the overall iteration for the cases will be(in a much simplified version) :-

```
(n-4)*(j-1)*n times.
```

But,j itself varies from 4 to n-1. So, j is kinda dependent on n. i.e.,`4<=j<=n-1`.  //so, here j will iterate n-5 times...

The exact treatment will be kinda this :-

```
n*n-5*n=n^3-5*n^2.
```

It is equal to `O(n^3)`.

So, going in the worst case analysis, the number of iterations will be **n^3-5*n^2** and it's time complexity will be **O(n^3)**.